# UserInteraction Enabled but UIElement still does not react

Tags: ios, swift

[image]So basically I have a comment cell which contains a couple of elements one, in particular, is the UIImageView which contains a profile picture for a user. I have enabled userInteraction on that element and even added a tapGesture. However the function in control of the operation that i want to run on this element still does not react.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

protocol CommentCellDelegate: class {
    func optionsButtonTapped(cell: CommentCell)
}
class CommentCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    weak var delegate: CommentCellDelegate? = nil
    weak var newCommentController: NewCommentsViewController?
    override var reuseIdentifier : String {
        get {
            return "cellID"
        }
        set {
            // nothing, because only red is allowed
        }
    }
    var didTapOptionsButtonForCell: ((CommentCell) -> Void)?

    var comment: CommentGrabbed?{
        didSet{
            guard let comment = comment else{
                return
            }
          //  print("apples")
            // textLabel.text = comment.content
            //shawn was also here
            profileImageView.loadImage(urlString: comment.user.profilePic!)
            //  print(comment.user.username)
            let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: comment.user.username!, attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14)])

            attributedText.append(NSAttributedString(string: " " + (comment.content), attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)]))
            textView.attributedText = attributedText


        }
    }

    let textView: UITextView = {
        let textView = UITextView()
        textView.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)
        textView.isScrollEnabled = false
        textView.isEditable = false
        return textView
    }()


    let profileImageView: CustomImageView = {
        let iv = CustomImageView()
        iv.clipsToBounds = true
        iv.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        iv.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleProfileTransition)))
        iv.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        return iv
    }()

    lazy var flagButton: UIButton = {
        let flagButton = UIButton(type: .system)
        flagButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "icons8-Info-64"), for: .normal)
        flagButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(optionsButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
        return flagButton
    }()

    @objc func optionsButtonTapped (){
        didTapOptionsButtonForCell?(self)
    }

    @objc func onOptionsTapped() {
        delegate?.optionsButtonTapped(cell: self)
    }
    @objc func handleProfileTransition(tapGesture: UITapGestureRecognizer){
        print("Tapped Image Cell")
    }



    override init(frame: CGRect){
        super.init(frame: frame)
        addSubview(textView)
        addSubview(profileImageView)
        addSubview(flagButton)
        textView.anchor(top: topAnchor, left: profileImageView.rightAnchor, bottom: bottomAnchor, right: rightAnchor, paddingTop: 4, paddingLeft: 4, paddingBottom: 4, paddingRight: 4, width: 0, height: 0)
        profileImageView.anchor(top: topAnchor, left: leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: nil, paddingTop: 8, paddingLeft: 8, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 40, height: 40)
        profileImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 40/2
        flagButton.anchor(top: topAnchor, left: nil, bottom: nil, right: rightAnchor, paddingTop: 4, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 4, width: 40, height: 40)
        flagButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(CommentCell.onOptionsTapped), for: .touchUpInside)

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }




}
```

Any ideas of what I could have done wrong?
UI Hiearchy

Comment: an you attach a screenshot of the document outline showing the tap gesture recognizer?

Comment: what do you mean

Comment: The left side bar on interface builder. Screenshot of the ui hierarchy

Comment: its programatic ui

Comment: oh wait, didn't see that. feel like a dumb horse rn.

Comment: see edits @Sam please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to set the gesture recognizer target to self, before self has been completely initialized.

Consider using lazy initialization for your `profileImageView`.

It should look like this:

```
lazy var profileImageView: CustomImageView = {
    let iv = CustomImageView()
    iv.clipsToBounds = true
    iv.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    iv.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleProfileTransition)))
    iv.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    return iv
}()
```

Comment: of course lazy var. lol every variable might as well be a lazy var lol
the one true answer to all lifes questions